# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{z^{2n}+1}$ converges when $\|z\|\neq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

I considered the partial fraction decomposition,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{z^{2n}+1}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{z^n-i}+\frac{1}{z^n+i}\bigg)
$$

is it sufficient to say that if $\|z\|<1$ then

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\bigg(\frac{1}{z^n-i}+\frac{1}{z^n+i}\bigg)={1 \over -i}+{1\over i}=0
$$

and if $\|z\|$>1 then the denominator grows without bound and hence the terms of the sequence also approach $0$? How would I show that this series represents an analytic function?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean $|z|$? Usually $||z||$ is reserved for norms.

Comment: We are worried about *how fast* we approach $0$. For $||z||\lt 1$, that I think is easier to grasp in the original form.

Comment: Ratio test (the limit version) is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the cases of $|z|<1$ and $|z|>1$ separately.

When $|z|<1$ and we consider the farther-out terms when $n>>1$, we see that the denominators approach $1$.  We may approximate the series as

$\sum {{z^n}\over{1}}$

which, for $|z|<1$, certainly does converge.  The actual series has terms smaller in magnitude then corresponding terms in this approximation. If anything that helps it converge better.  A basic theorem about the convergence of infinite series applies here.

For $|z|>1$ and $n>>1$, we can see that $z^{2n}$ gets very large.  We make an approximation by ignoring the $1$:

$\sum {{z^n}\over{z^{2n}}}$

Again, after some trivial algebra we see this converges.  Again, comparing to the actual series, we see that actual terms are smaller than corresponding terms in the approximation.