# Uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{n}}{1+z^{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \dfrac{z^{n}}{1+z^{2n}}$ converges uniformly over the compact subsets of $\{z\in \mathbb C : |z|\neq 1\}$.

if we assume $|z| = 1$. Then, by the limit test,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{1^n+1^{-n}}=\frac{1}{2}\neq 0$$
therefore, the series diverges.

but, I don't know how to bound the series to use Weierstrass M-test.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/744605.

Comment: For $\lvert z \rvert < 1$ and $n \ge 1$, you have that $\left\lvert \frac{z^n}{1 + z^{2 n}} \right\rvert \le \lvert z^n \rvert$, and the geometric series converges.

Comment: @vonbrand: No, $|1 + z^{2n}|$ can be less than one for $|z| < 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Note that $$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{1 + z^{2n}} \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^n} $$

Comment: There is no $\le$ relation for complex numbers.

Comment: I think you forgot your absolute values.

Comment: @Allawonder: With absolute values the estimate is wrong.

Comment: @MartinR Why so? Isn't $|1+z^{2n}|\ge |z|^{2n},$ well at least for points outside the unit disc?

Comment: @Allawonder: That is already wrong for $z=0$. And in order to estimate the LHS you need a *lower* bound for $|1 + z^{2n}|$. Also the RHS converges only for $|z| > 1$.

Comment: @MartinR See edit. I meant for points *outside* the disc.

Comment: @Allawonder: Still does not work. Try $n=1$ and $z= 1.1 i$, $z^2 = -1.21$.

Comment: I'm a little confused, if $| z |> 1$, how could bound the function